# Any good JavaScript/HTML/CSS plugins/indenters/syntaxcolourers for Vim?

Tags: software-rec, javascript, plugins, gvim, vi

Have tried a couple of JavaScript indenters but all seems to have flaws and warts. Are there any good JavaScript/HTML/CSS plugins/indenters/syntaxcolourers for Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58825/javascript-syntax-highlighting-in-vim/58953#58953
- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1491
- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1840

If you like this answer, vote it up.  Its good for the community.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5Fid=1830)?

EDIT: This is a very old answer.
The above link does not work any more, but the plugin is still available
from the
[Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150427075653/https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%255Fid=1830)
and can be downloaded from
[this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150427075653/https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=6885).

Just in case, I reproduce it here below:

```
" Description:  html indenter
" Author:   Johannes Zellner <johannes@zellner.org>
" Last Change:  Tue, 27 Apr 2004 10:28:39 CEST
"       Restoring 'cpo' and 'ic' added by Bram 2006 May 5
" Globals:  g:html_indent_tags     -- indenting tags
"       g:html_indent_strict       -- inhibit 'O O' elements
"       g:html_indent_strict_table -- inhibit 'O -' elements

" Only load this indent file when no other was loaded.
if exists("b:did_indent")
    finish
endif
let b:did_indent = 1


" [-- local settings (must come before aborting the script) --]
setlocal indentexpr=HtmlIndentGet(v:lnum)
setlocal indentkeys=o,O,*<Return>,<>>,{,}


if exists('g:html_indent_tags')
    unlet g:html_indent_tags
endif

" [-- helper function to assemble tag list --]
fun! <SID>HtmlIndentPush(tag)
    if exists('g:html_indent_tags')
    let g:html_indent_tags = g:html_indent_tags.'\|'.a:tag
    else
    let g:html_indent_tags = a:tag
    endif
endfun


" [-- <ELEMENT ? - - ...> --]
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('a')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('abbr')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('acronym')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('address')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('b')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('bdo')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('big')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('blockquote')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('button')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('caption')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('center')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('cite')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('code')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('colgroup')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('del')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('dfn')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('dir')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('div')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('dl')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('em')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('fieldset')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('font')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('form')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('frameset')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('h1')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('h2')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('h3')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('h4')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('h5')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('h6')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('i')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('iframe')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('ins')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('kbd')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('label')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('legend')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('map')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('menu')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('noframes')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('noscript')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('object')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('ol')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('optgroup')
" call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('pre')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('q')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('s')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('samp')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('script')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('select')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('small')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('span')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('strong')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('style')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('sub')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('sup')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('table')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('textarea')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('title')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('tt')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('u')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('ul')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('var')


" [-- <ELEMENT ? O O ...> --]
if !exists('g:html_indent_strict')
    call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('body')
    call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('head')
    call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('html')
    call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('tbody')
endif


" [-- <ELEMENT ? O - ...> --]
if !exists('g:html_indent_strict_table')
    call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('th')
    call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('td')
    call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('tr')
    call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('tfoot')
    call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('thead')
endif

delfun <SID>HtmlIndentPush

let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo-=C

" [-- count indent-increasing tags of line a:lnum --]
fun! <SID>HtmlIndentOpen(lnum, pattern)
    let s = substitute('x'.getline(a:lnum),
    \ '.\{-}\(\(<\)\('.a:pattern.'\)\>\)', "\1", 'g')
    let s = substitute(s, "[^\1].*$", '', '')
    return strlen(s)
endfun

" [-- count indent-decreasing tags of line a:lnum --]
fun! <SID>HtmlIndentClose(lnum, pattern)
    let s = substitute('x'.getline(a:lnum),
    \ '.\{-}\(\(<\)/\('.a:pattern.'\)\>>\)', "\1", 'g')
    let s = substitute(s, "[^\1].*$", '', '')
    return strlen(s)
endfun

" [-- count indent-increasing '{' of (java|css) line a:lnum --]
fun! <SID>HtmlIndentOpenAlt(lnum)
    return strlen(substitute(getline(a:lnum), '[^{]\+', '', 'g'))
endfun

" [-- count indent-decreasing '}' of (java|css) line a:lnum --]
fun! <SID>HtmlIndentCloseAlt(lnum)
    return strlen(substitute(getline(a:lnum), '[^}]\+', '', 'g'))
endfun

" [-- return the sum of indents respecting the syntax of a:lnum --]
fun! <SID>HtmlIndentSum(lnum, style)
    if a:style == match(getline(a:lnum), '^\s*</')
    if a:style == match(getline(a:lnum), '^\s*</\<\('.g:html_indent_tags.'\)\>')
        let open = <SID>HtmlIndentOpen(a:lnum, g:html_indent_tags)
        let close = <SID>HtmlIndentClose(a:lnum, g:html_indent_tags)
        if 0 != open || 0 != close
        return open - close
        endif
    endif
    endif
    if '' != &syntax &&
    \ synIDattr(synID(a:lnum, 1, 1), 'name') =~ '\(css\|java\).*' &&
    \ synIDattr(synID(a:lnum, strlen(getline(a:lnum)), 1), 'name')
    \ =~ '\(css\|java\).*'
    if a:style == match(getline(a:lnum), '^\s*}')
        return <SID>HtmlIndentOpenAlt(a:lnum) - <SID>HtmlIndentCloseAlt(a:lnum)
    endif
    endif
    return 0
endfun

fun! s:getSyntaxName(lnum, re)
    return synIDattr(synID(a:lnum, match(getline(a:lnum), a:re) + 1, 0), "name")
endfun

fun! s:isSyntaxElem(lnum, re, elem)
    if getline(a:lnum) =~ a:re && s:getSyntaxName(a:lnum, a:re) == a:elem
        return 1
    endif
    return 0
endfun

fun! HtmlIndentGet(lnum)
    " Find a non-empty line above the current line.
    let lnum = prevnonblank(a:lnum - 1)

    " Hit the start of the file, use zero indent.
    if lnum == 0
    return 0
    endif

    let restore_ic = &ic
    setlocal ic " ignore case

    " [-- special handling for <pre>: no indenting --]
    if getline(a:lnum) =~ '\c</pre>'
        \ || 0 < searchpair('\c<pre>', '', '\c</pre>', 'nWb')
        \ || 0 < searchpair('\c<pre>', '', '\c</pre>', 'nW')
    " we're in a line with </pre> or inside <pre> ... </pre>
    if restore_ic == 0
      setlocal noic
    endif
    return -1
    endif

    " [-- special handling for <javascript>: use cindent --]
    let js = '<script.*type\s*=\s*.*java'
    if   0 < searchpair(js, '', '</script>', 'nWb')
    \ || 0 < searchpair(js, '', '</script>', 'nW')
    " we're inside javascript
    if getline(lnum) !~ js && getline(a:lnum) !~ js
        if restore_ic == 0
          setlocal noic
        endif
        " Open and close bracket:
        if s:isSyntaxElem(lnum, '{', "javaScriptBraces") && s:isSyntaxElem(a:lnum, '}', "javaScriptBraces")
            return indent(lnum)
        elseif s:isSyntaxElem(lnum, '{', "javaScriptBraces")
            return indent(lnum) + &sw
        elseif s:isSyntaxElem(a:lnum, '}', "javaScriptBraces")
            if s:isSyntaxElem(lnum, 'break', 'javaScriptBranch') && ! s:isSyntaxElem(lnum, '\(case\|default\)', "javaScriptLabel")
                return indent(lnum) - 2 * &sw
            endif
            return indent(lnum) - &sw
        endif

        " cases:
        if s:isSyntaxElem(lnum, '\(case\|default\)', "javaScriptLabel") && s:isSyntaxElem(a:lnum, '\(case\|default\)', "javaScriptLabel")
            return indent(lnum)
        elseif s:isSyntaxElem(lnum, '\(case\|default\)', "javaScriptLabel")
            return indent(lnum) + &sw
        elseif s:isSyntaxElem(a:lnum, '\(case\|default\)', "javaScriptLabel")
            return indent(lnum) - &sw
        endif

        if getline(a:lnum) =~ '\c</script>'
            let scriptline = prevnonblank(search(js, 'bW'))
            if scriptline > 0
                return indent(scriptline)
            endif
        endif
        return indent(lnum)
    endif
    endif

    if getline(a:lnum) =~ '\c</\?body' || getline(a:lnum) =~ '\c</\?html' || getline(a:lnum) =~ '\c</\?head'
        return 0
    endif
    if getline(lnum) =~ '\c</\?body' || getline(lnum) =~ '\c</\?html' || getline(lnum) =~ '\c</\?head'
        return 0
    endif

    if getline(lnum) =~ '\c</pre>'
    " line before the current line a:lnum contains
    " a closing </pre>. --> search for line before
    " starting <pre> to restore the indent.
    let preline = prevnonblank(search('\c<pre>', 'bW') - 1)
    if preline > 0
        if restore_ic == 0
          setlocal noic
        endif
        return indent(preline)
    endif
    endif

    let ind = <SID>HtmlIndentSum(lnum, -1)
    let ind = ind + <SID>HtmlIndentSum(a:lnum, 0)

    if restore_ic == 0
    setlocal noic
    endif

    return indent(lnum) + (&sw * ind)
endfun

let &cpo = s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save

" [-- EOF <runtime>/indent/html.vim --]
```

Comment: Nope has to try that.

Comment: As of today, this link is broken.

Comment: @freginold: I fixed the problem, but do not know how well it works today after so many years.